# T test to find differentially expressed genes in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix which contains the genes and the mrna.

```
ID_REF    GSM362168 GSM362169 GSM362170 GSM362171 GSM362172 GSM362173 GSM362174      
244901_at   5.171072  5.207896  5.191145  5.067809  5.010239  5.556884  4.879528      
244902_at   5.296012  5.460796  5.419633  5.440318  5.234789  7.567894  6.908795
```

I wanted to  find the differentially expressed genes from the matrix using t test and i carried out the following.

```
stat=mt.teststat(control,classlabel,test="t",na=.mt.naNUM,nonpara="n")
```

and I get the following error

```
Error in is.factor(classlabel) : object 'classlabel' not found.
```

I am not sure how I have to assign the classlabels.Is it the right way to find the differentially expressed genes.

The classlabel should be a vector of integers corresponding to observation (column) class labels. I do not understand what that is.

Comment: 1) Could you add a **reproductible** example ? 2) Could you tell us what package you're using ?

Comment: amusing the multtest package in R.

Comment: You need to edit this post to display the data correctly. Indent all lines of data/code with 4 spaces. You seem to have probeset IDs interspersed with measurement values.

Comment: Also: have you read the mt.teststat help page, using ?mt.teststat. It tells you that the first argument to the function is your matrix, the second (classlabel) is "A vector of integers corresponding to observation (column) class labels." There's no mention of that vector in your question.

Comment: yes i was not sure as to what the vector is ??

Answer (score 1):

If you open the documentation for mt.teststat:

```
?mt.teststat
```

and scroll down to the end, you'll see an example using the "Golub data":

```
data(golub)
teststat <- mt.teststat(golub, golub.cl)
```

If you look at *golub.cl*,it will become clear what the *classlabel* vector should look like:

```
golub.cl
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

In this case, 0 or 1 are labels for two classes of sample. There should be as many values in the vector as you have samples, in the same order that the samples appear in the data matrix.  You can also look at:

```
?golub
```

> golub.cl: numeric vector indicating the tumor class, 27 acute
>             lymphoblastic leukemia (ALL) cases (code 0) and 11 acute
>             myeloid leukemia (AML) cases (code 1).

So you need to create a similar vector, with labels (0, 1, ...) for however many classes you have for your own data.

Comment: I saw the documentation alreadybut was not able to understand how I have to create the classlabel for my data.

Comment: Well, what classes do you have? Looking at the GEO experiment I see things like "root_control_total" and "roottip_hypoxia_pWOL". So you need to group your samples into the groups that you want to compare, then simply assign the labels to them. So "root_control_total" could = 0, "roottip_hypoxia_pWOL" = 1 and so on.

Comment: Another approach that you may find easier: go to the GEO series for these samples (e.g. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE14578) and look for the "GEO2R" link, to do the analysis online.

Comment: I would like to know what would be the best approach to find the differntially expressed genes if i have a matrix of probesets and the data in control condition.Could I still use the T test??

Comment: Depends how many groups you have. If there are 2: "control" + "something else" then yes, you might use some kind of t-test. Otherwise, something like limma (used by GEO2R) is more appropriate.

Comment: Could anyone please let me know the best way to compute differentialyexpressed genes for mutliple variables in a single dataset ??